# Suffix array and counting distinct substrings of specific length

Tags: algorithms, strings, substrings

I am trying to use the suffix array, and the LCP array to count all distinct substrings of a specified length.

I started with the algorithm for counting ALL distinct substrings. I solved it after this explanation: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/count-distinct-substrings-string-using-suffix-array/  . The problem right now is that I can't figure out how to only count the substrings of my given length, and not all possibilities.

I also computed the array which tells me how many suffixes are lexicographically smaller than suffix_array[i].

Any ideas what I could use to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The geeksforgeeks solution gives an efficient algorithm that accomplishes the following:

- Sorts the suffixes of the input string in lexicographic order.
- For every two adjacent suffixes in this order, finds the longest common prefix.

If you are after the number of distinct substrings of length $\ell$, you should proceed as follows:

- If the first suffix has length at least $\ell$, initialize your counter with 1, otherwise with 0.
- Now go over all the suffixes in lexicographic order. If the new suffix has length at least $\ell$ and the lcp with the preceding suffix has length smaller than $\ell$, then increment the counter.

For example, suppose that the string is `ababa`, and you're after substrings of length $\ell = 3$. The ordered suffixes are `a`, `aba`, `ababa`, `ba`, `baba`. The algorithm proceeds as follows:

- The first suffix `a` is shorter than $\ell$, so the counter starts at 0.
- The second suffix `aba` has length at least $\ell$, and the lcp with the preceding suffix has length less than $\ell$, so increment the counter. (We have discovered `aba`.)
- The third suffix `ababa` has length at least $\ell$, but the lcp with the preceding suffix also has length at least $\ell$.
- The fourth suffix `ba` has length less than $\ell$.
- The fifth suffix `baba` has length at least $\ell$, and the lcp with the preceding suffix has length less than $\ell$, so increment the counter. (We have discovered `bab`.)